# connected sets on metric space

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces

Given a metric space $(Z,d)$ and two closed subsets $X,Y \subset Z$.

Let $X$, $\, X \cup Y$ and $X \cap Y$ be connected.

How can I show that $Y$ is connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y = O_2 \sqcup O_2$, with $O_1, O_2$ open in $Y$.

Then $X\cap Y = X \cap O_1 \sqcup X \cap O_2$ with $X \cap O_i$ open in $X$ for $i\in\{1,2\}$.

<s>But $X \cap Y$ is connected, hence $O_1 = ∅ \lor O_2 = ∅$</s>.

**Edit:**

But $X \cap Y$ is connected, hence $X \cap O_1 = ∅ \lor X \cap O_2 = ∅$.

Without loss of generality let's assume $X \cap O_1 = ∅$.

We then have $X \cup Y = O_1 \sqcup (X \cup O_2)$.

But $X \cup Y$ is connected, therefore $O_1 = \emptyset$ or $O_2= \emptyset \, \land\, X = \emptyset$.

Hence $Y$ is connected.

Comment: Does $\sqcup$ denote union? Then your proof is incorrect. There's nothing that prevents $X\cap O_i$ to be empty and therefore you don't reach an contradiction. Note that you have to use all prerequisites to prove that it is true (except that you can loosen the requirement that $Z$ is metric).

Comment: To illustrate skyking'S point, take $Z=\Bbb R$, $X=[0,1]$, and $Y=\{0\}\cup [0,1]$. Then $Y$ can be broken up into two open disjoint sets, but it does not follow just from $X\cap Y$ being connected that $Y$ is connected.

Comment: thanks for pointing out! i corrected the proof

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:Y\to \{0,1\}$ be continuous. Then $f|_{X\cap Y}$ must also be continuous, and hence constant. Assume WLOG that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in X\cap Y$.

Define $\hat{f}:X\cup Y\to \{0,1\}$ by $\hat{f}(x)=0$ for $x\in X$, and $\hat{f}|_{Y}=f$. This is clearly well defined, and continuous by the gluing lemma. Thus it must be constant, so $f$ must be constant and therefore the result follows.

Note that this proof never uses the fact that $Z$ is metric, only topological, and that $X$ is connected. We do use the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are closed. Do you see where?

Comment: do you also know a more 'elementary' proof using only the notions from above?

Comment: @augustinsouchy unfortunately no, since this proof only uses the definition of connected and the gluing lemma, which is a fairly standard lemma.

Comment: @augustinsouchy how does your class define connected?

Comment: good point! if there are no two disjoint open sets such that their union is the original set

Comment: @augustinsouchy this is the same as that all continuous functions from the space to $\{0,1\}$ are constant, is that clear?

Comment: it will be, lemme think about that!

Comment: @augustinsouchy Hint(or definition really): we put the discrete topology on $\{0,1\}$, so $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open sets.